# IPTables not blocking IPStresser

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall, ddos

I have been trying four days to block DDoS attacks with no success. I want to block anything that isn't whitelisted.

This is my idea on OS Centos 7:

```
//Delete All Existing Rules
iptables --flush

//Set Default Chain Policies
iptables -P INPUT REJECT
iptables -P OUTPUT REJECT
iptables -P FORWARD REJECT

//This is the IP i want to whitelist
//I think this line doesnt work, because i cant connect BUT...
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 180.243.22.122 -j ACCEPT

//Loop here for add desired future IP
```

In my test nobody can connect to any port but I can attack it myself with DDoS using any UDP stresser... Why?

Comment: policy is reject, where is allow rule for legit traffic? btw, I don't think REJECT can be set as policy, try with drop but you will need to create rules in INPUT chain that will allow legit traffic, and consider OUTPUT chain too.. you need to be able to respond to traffic incoming and allow legit traffic outwards...

Comment: Get a hardware firewall

Answer (score 1):

You are actively rejecting any connections by the default policy REJECT by
`iptables -P INPUT REJECT`.

To block connections from an IP you would use DROP or REJECT instead of ACCEPT in your rule:

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 180.243.22.122 -j DROP`

The problem you are experiencing is because you are rejecting all connections, and by using REJECT you will be sending an ICMP packet to the source telling it that the connection was rejected. You can instead use DROP which will not send a response.
The issue with not being able to connect to any service is caused because you have not opened any incoming connections, which you could do with e.g.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <port no.> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport <port no.> -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was using DROP then i read over there REJECT its better, anyway,
I had the same problem using DROP, check this [link of another question using DROP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449498/iptables-not-blocking-ipstresser)
So i understand these rules are blocking me from connect but it doesnt stop the attack :/

Answer (score 1):

Three things that concern me here.

**1.** As others have mentioned, your policy is set to `REJECT`. Not even sure that's a valid target for policy---I believe it's just a target extension but double check your manpage.

The target you want is `DROP`. You start with something like this (**make sure you are on console and not SSH since you may be disconnected and locked out**):

```
iptables -F # Clear out chains
iptables -Z # Delete user chains
iptables -X # Reset counters

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP # Do not like this, more on that in 2nd and 3rd points
```

**2.** The way you are handling `INPUT` should work fine if you are only getting connections from that one IP address. However, you will be having issues establishing connection because all `OUTPUT` packets are being filtered. You should be doing something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 180.243.22.122 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 180.243.22.122 -j ACCEPT
```

That being said...

**3.** Using `DROP` as your `OUTPUT` policy could have tons of unintended consequences. Example would be getting updates from repositories and failing DNS queries. Quite frankly, egress rules are rarely justified in my opinion. I'd do the following:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT # Replace the other policy

# This accepts all related connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This will be saner and less of a headache.

---

Just to sum it up, this is what I'd go with:

```
iptables -F # Clear out chains
iptables -Z # Delete user chains
iptables -X # Reset counters

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Accept loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT

# Accept based on state
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# IP-based exceptions
iptables -A INPUT -s 180.243.22.122 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I was using DROP then i read over there REJECT its better, anyway,
I had the same problem using DROP, check this [link of another question using DROP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449498/iptables-not-blocking-ipstresser)
So i understand these rules are blocking me from connect but it doesnt stop the attack :/

Comment: @Martini002 Elaborated a bit more. Hope that helps.